# Apps Script body.replaceText() will not match multiple lines

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs, re2

Given the following text in a Google Doc:

```
@1Bryan Smith
1234 Alameda Ln
Palm Springs, CO
92264@

@2Jerry Macnamara
4568 Montagonal Ave
Aspertine, MD
29382@
```

I want to be able to programmatically delete the block of text for either Bryan Smith or Jerry Macnamara.  To do this, I am attempting to use the replaceText() function of Apps Script body element.  The problem is, the regex is not functioning as expected.

```
var i = 2;
var regex = new RegExp('^@' + i + '([\\s\\S]*)@$', 'm');
```

The above regular expression *works*, but body.replaceText() does not take a RegExp as an argument, only strings representing an expression.  I have tried replicating the above regex in string format as such:

```
body.replaceText('(m)^@' + i + '([\\s\\S]*)@$', '');
```

It can not find a match.  I believe I may be setting the m flag incorrectly.

The replaceText() function must be used, I do not want to edit the doc text directly as a string as it will mess up the formatting and images in the doc.

Documenation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern-replacement

Sample script for testing (Tools -> Script editor): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/136_o9acI_rtHf0njRapt1i-r0F_ZWPAXtKYVkUmpBlc/edit#gid=0

Comment: `body.replaceText('(?s)@' + i + '.*?@', '')` seems to work though. Do you really need to check for line boundaries?

Comment: I removed `javascript` tag since the code you have issues with is related to the RE2 regex engine.

Comment: I've updated to `body.replaceText('(?s)@' + i + '.*?@', '');` and it still is not finding a match in the doc.  Wiktor could you share with me the Sheet / Doc you have been able to get it working with?  I've also tried modifying the above to (?sm), same result.

Comment: @TheMaster It works if you use soft breaks, SHIFT+ENTER.